# Referencing a mainform from another mainform

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am trying to reference form A from form B using VBA in order to give form A's control a value.

So far I've got this:

Forms!FormName!ControlName.Caption = valueToAssign

It's not working for me. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Caption is for setting labels.

For all other controls it is Value:

```
Forms!FormName!ControlName.Value = valueToAssign
```

Comment: I want to give the labels caption a string.

Comment: Then you may have to call `Forms!FormName.Repaind` after setting the caption(s).